# Why I am unable to access my forked repository using GitHub API

Tags: github-api

I have a custom application which is able to access the Enterprise repository using my Personal Access Token.

But when I forked the same enterprise repository I am unable to access it using the same application which uses the GitHub API and my personal access token.

> So the enterprise repo looks like this : my-org-name/test-repo
>
> And my forked repo looks like this: andy/test-repo

When I authenticate using personal access token and try to get the owner name for my repo like below using PHP KnpLab GitHub API SDK as below:

```
$this->gitHubClient
                ->api('repo')
                ->find($repoName)['repositories'][0]['owner']
```

It throws exception (No 400 type or access or forbidden exception). When I tried to check the 'repositories' array, the array itself is empty.

I have checked all the configuration twice, E.g API End point, Branch Name, Repo Name, etc. And everything is looking OK. It appears to be some access issue but not quite sure what I need to do to ask the Admin so that proper permission is set on my account for accessing the repo.

How should I solve this issue?

Edit: Did some further testing. I am able to access some other repos that looks like andy\another-repo. So only this specific repo I am unable to access.